# iOS drawRect: is it possible to clear the Graphics Context?

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics, drawrect, cgcontext

I'm writing an iPad app and I have a custom view where I override `drawRect` to do a bunch of drawing. I have a timer calling the `setNeedsLayout` to refresh the graphics.

When I profile my application I see that the memory taken up by the application goes from 1.5MB to 600MB as the animation unfolds.

Also the previously drawn graphics don't go away, so I draw a white square over them before redrawing the new graphics.

I'm guessing some of the paths or shapes are remaining in the context. How can I clear it (remove everything from it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of clearing the graphics context.  You're probably leaking objects.  Use the Leaks template in Instruments to help track them down.  Or post your `drawRect:` code and we might be able to see some leaks.

Comment: Thank you Rob! I verified that I had no memory leaks and I didn't have any. As it turns out I think I'm just reading Instruments wrong. I was looking at the "Overall Bytes" column instead of the "Live bytes" column. Looks like the "Live Bytes" for all allocation never goes beyond 635KB. Thanks for helping me verify that I wasn't doing anything wrong inside drawRect:!